Как задать URL-маппинг в сервлетах?
Я пишу небольшое вэб-приложение с использованием Java сервлетов, и у меня возник вопрос.
У меня есть сервлет, который отображает информацию о проекте используя его id.
Поэтому в сервлете URL-маппинг указан как /projects/*, и уже в сервлете происходят некоторые проверки.
Также, у меня есть сервлет, который выдает информацию о задачах этого проекта, и я хотел задать ему URL /projects/*/tasks, но это не работает. Что делать?

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

Вы хотите странного, cм. ответ на EngSO: Servlet and path parameters like /xyz/{value}/test, how to map in web.xml?. Вероятно, у вас должны быть URL вида projects/{id} и projects/{id}/tasks.

@NowhereMan Да, именно этого я и хотел. Просто в спринге можно явно указать pathVariable, и я хотел сделать такой же функционал на чистых сервлетах. Видимо, с помощью аннотации такого не добиться, и придется обрабатывать запрос уже в самих методах. Спасибо за ссылку на статью, буду опираться на нее

Очень просто, для каждого сервлета выбрать свой уникальный путь. Если /projects/* уже выбран, то можно второй сервлет замапить на /tasks/*.
